# Error 1 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib'

Tags: c++, libraries, ogre3d

I'm trying out Ogre3d and following this tutorial 
http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Setting+Up+An+Application+-+Visual+Studio#New_Project

I got 1.9.0 Ogre version and followed it, but still getting this error.

If I check $(OGRE_HOME)\boost\lib I see there's a file called 'libboost_thread-vc110-mt-gd-1_55.lib' instead of 120. I tried renaming it, checkin if it was in the C++\General\Aditional libraries and it was.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Those numbers indicate the VisualStudio version that was used to compile Boost. You can't just rename them and hope for everything to work. Recompile Boost using VS2013 (vc12) and it'll generate the correct lib for you.

Comment: It didn't work, I tried recompiling, regenerating and it didnt work. Same error

Comment: Did compiling with VS2013 generate a lib with that exact name?